# AWS has multiple volumes for one site?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I set up a Mediawiki site on Amazon Web Services (AWS).  It works fine.  I actually have two sites.  I was on the EC2 dashboard and noticed there were three volumes.  For some reason the MediaWiki site has two volumes instead of just one.  I don't remember setting it up that way but I may have.  One is 8 gigabites and one is 12 gigabites.  The 8GB one was set up first, about 20 minutes before the second.  Both volume types are gp2.  Under the "Attachment Information" field, it shows "[instanceID] [Sitename] :/dev/xvda (attached)" and "[instanceID] [Sitename] :/dev/sdf (attached)". The instanceID and Sitename are the same.  The state of both is "in-use" and the volume status for both is OK.  Which one is the site running on?  Can I shut one of these down?  I don't think I need 8+12 gigs or anything close to that.  If I had set up the 12g one first, I would think I set up the second intending to shut down the first.  If I shut the 12g one down and it turns out to somehow mess up my site, can I re-instate it?

Answer (score 0):

You can set one or more EBS volumes to one EBS instance, but one EBS can´t be attached with more than one instances.

You can try to create an AMI of your EC2 instance (remember check the "no reboot instance) and start other EC2 instance without EBS attached, just your application.